# TensorFlow 2.0: Function with @tf.function decorator doesn't take numpy functions

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am writing a function to implement a model in TensorFlow 2.0. It takes `image_batch` (a batch of image data in numpy RGB format) and performs some specific data augmentation task that I need. The line that is causing me problems is:

```
@tf.function
def augment_data(image_batch, labels):
    import numpy as np
    from tensorflow.image import flip_left_right

    image_batch = np.append(image_batch, flip_left_right(image_batch), axis=0)

    [ ... ]
```

`numpy`'s `.append()` function doesn't work anymore when I put the `@tf.function` decorator on top of it. It returns:

> ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated

When I use the `np.append()` command outside of the function, or without the `@tf.function` on top, the code runs without problems.

Is this normal? Am I forced to remove the decorator to make it work? Or is this a bug, due to the fact that TensorFlow 2.0 is still a beta version? In that case, how can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just wrap numpy ops into `tf.py_function`

```py
def append(image_batch, tf_func):
    return np.append(image_batch, tf_func, axis=0)

@tf.function
def augment_data(image_batch):
    image = tf.py_function(append, inp=[image_batch, tf.image.flip_left_right(image_batch)], Tout=[tf.float32])
    return image
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried your code. Only one thing returned error: you must write `np.append` instead of just `append`. Apart from that eveything works, thank you for the reply.

Comment: In this case append is a user defined function, but it's can use np.append as well.

Comment: Shall I use `tf.py_function` even for more "basic" ones, like `int()` ? I'm now forcing a number to be integer, and I got: `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`. Is it the same problem? Thanks

Comment: I think with regard to `int()` it's another problem.